# Laravel show data on blade view from mysql table

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm just to do some try to visualize data of mysql table filled with factory faker fzaninotto.

This is my factory file:

```
$factory->define(Boat::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [

        'name'=> $faker -> name,
        'images' => json_encode(["description" => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 2, $variableNbWords = true),
                                 "url" => $faker->imageUrl($width = 800, $height = 600, 'cats', true, 'Faker', true),
                                 "sortOrder" => $faker->randomDigitNotNull] 
                               ),

];
```

This is schema for migration :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('boats', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->json('images');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Cotroller fuction :

```
public function listBoats()
{
    $data = Boat::all();
    return view('frontendViews.listBoats',['data'=>$data]);
}
```

Now i can access data with {{$boat->name}} for get name of boat, but how can i get url for src link of images?

```
    'name'=> $faker -> name,
'images' => json_encode(["description" => $faker->sentence($nbWords = 2, $variableNbWords = true),
                                     "url" => $faker->imageUrl($width = 800, $height = 600, 'cats', true, 'Faker', true),
                                     "sortOrder" => $faker->randomDigitNotNull] 
                                   ),
```

Thank you

Comment: Use ```{{ json_decode($boat->images, true)["url"] }}```

Comment: @Kristian it just seems to be what I was looking for, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using `{{ $boat->name }}` to access the name, then you could use `{{ $boat->images }}` to access the JSON formatted string of the image

Since the images are stored in database in JSON format (as you described), then the JSON formatted string should look like this:

```
{
  "description" : "this is the image of a car",
  "url" : "https://somewhere.com/img/car.png",
  "sortOrder" : 1
}
```

In order to access the URL, you need to "decode"/"deserialize"/"parse" the JSON, and then take the "URL" key/property

In native PHP, you do JSON serialization and deserialization with `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`

Therefore, in order to get the image URL: `{{ json_decode($boat->images, true)["url"] }}`

If you need reference about JSON format:

- https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp
- https://www.json.org/json-en.html